# Logged in user changes automatically on page refresh

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a webpart on a site page. The URL is `http://speedsoln:7779/SitePages/details.aspx`. The webpart fetches the domain name of the logged in user and queries into a list to get corresponding user id (employee info list) and the other details like first name, last name, address, etc.

On this page, there is a mysterious thing happening. Suppose in the employee info list there are details of 2 users: User A and USer B. Then, we loggin into the site as user A, now when we browse to the above URL, then we can see details of user A. If we refresh this page, then, **sometimes**, in the top right corner the logged in name automatically changes to User B and details of User B are loaded on the webpart. On next F5, we see that User A is logged in and User A's details appear on webpart. On next F5, User B, and so on...

On this webpart we are using ajax control toolkit accordion and forms view edit/item template... Any idea whats happening and what to look out for?

Comment: Can you show us the code that does the User object querying ? I have had a similar issue once, where I was using UserId's from one site collection to lookup the user in another Site Collection, and obviously the Id's were different and not returning the correct user. You need to make sure you use web.EnsureUser I believe

Comment: Have you checked the Credential Manager in Windows Control Panel?  If you've been logging into SharePoint as different users you may find default account login details saved here.

Comment: try disabling Kerberos authentication and set it to NTLM and then check.

Comment: Could you add some additional detail to your answer? Right now it's not clear to me why you are suggesting that Kerberos could cause this symptom.

Comment: 1. We are not using kerberos... 2. If at all someone is using kerberos then it is a technical architects decision which cannot be overridden once setup because there is no proof that kerberos would cause it. Any ways its not kerberos here.

Comment: also see the behavior if you create a fresh new web application and a site collection using NTLM authentication. Is the behavior the same?

Comment: Dibyendu is suggesting the problem might be Kerberos because that was in fact my issue (see the linked post). Once I flipped it to NTLM, the problem went away.