# Incorrect user name displaying on page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, login, credentials

We just built a new SP 2013 farm. For some reason when I access the sites, I see I am sometimes logged in as one of our service accounts (sp_crawl). If I refresh the browser, it switches to my normal AD account. I haven't determined a pattern, it seems rather random. Sometimes it opens as me, other times the crawl account. Sometimes it takes multiple refreshes before it switches. My coworker also saw the crawl account, but even more concerning was she saw my name too.

Any ideas?

We are using standard http and Kerberos and have UPS set up and synced.

Edit: I looked in the web app user policy and none of the entries have "Account operates as System" checked.

Pertaining to the duplicate question, I did reset my browser and checked windows credential manager (it has nothing in it). However, my coworker was having the same issue.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92463/logged-in-user-changes-automatically-on-page-refresh

Comment: I called Microsoft and the engineer determined the problem was being caused by Kerberos. He said the SPNs were probably not set up correctly. Once I switched the site to NTLM, the problem went away. I don't have the option to post this as the answer for some reason...

Comment: This problem was resolved. I was able to get SP to work with Kerberos. It turns out there was a problem with our load balancer. When I edited my local host file and pointed it to a WFE, bypassing the load balancer, the problem disappeared!

Comment: The problem was our F5 load balancer. It required configuration changes to work with Kerberos/SharePoint 2013. From F5's documentation: If the OneConnect feature is used with a SharePoint web application that is configured for Kerberos authentication, AND the SharePoint servers are using Windows 2012 or 2012 R2 (or if using Windows 2008 R2, the AuthPersistNonNTLM value is set to true), clients may experience issues with authentication after deploying the iApp template for either SharePoint 2010 or 2013. 

They have instructions in their documentation on how to solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

To be honest this sounds a lot like the same issue I've seen in our own environment, and once again at a client. But these two are a minority of cases.

Here's additional info:

- http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/56a3aaae-14c5-40dd-b87b-23c046f75980/sharepoint-2013-random-authentication-issue-where-users-are-suddenly-anonymous
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b1cec90c-c8e4-4a7c-9407-b98ce237c7f0/sharepoint-app-connecting-to-search-rest-api-with-oauth-random-claim-fail

If I keep the Distributed Cache disabled the issue is gone. That's not a recommended approach however.

This post about the Logon Token Cache looks interesting to follow up on:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2013/03/27/appfabric-caching-and-sharepoint-1.aspx

Did you, in your environment, modify any of the values of Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig such as lifetimes?

Comment: I had some errors in the ULS about Distributed Cache, but I ran use-cachecluster, checked the health, and everything looked good with it. I don't recall the errors now. I didn't mess with Get-SPSecurityTokenServiceConfig. I'll check your links.

Comment: I stopped the Distributed Cache on the 2 WFEs. I see if the problem goes away and get to you. Thanks!

Comment: OK, I have been in the site for about 20 minutes clicking all around and it seems like the problem is gone since I stopped the Distributed Cache. I'll make this as the answer and post later what I did to resolve it. Thanks again Steven!

Comment: I wouldn't say stopping the DC is a definite solution. Other things such as the Newsfeed rely on it. See it as a temporary fix.

Comment: After restarting the DC cluster yesterday, the problem seemed to have gone away. However, the problem just came back this morning.

Comment: Confirmed. I haven't found a permanent solution yet. May be worth to open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature in SharePoint 2013 called MDS (minimal download strategy), try to turn this off in site settings -> site features. Then, check if the issue persists and give your feedback.

Comment: This seems very unrelated given how MDS works (partial reloading of pages etc)

Comment: yes, but it is related to the inbuilt javascript and for some reason which I am not aware of resolves the issue atleast for me.

Comment: I did shut down MDS on one site due to problems with editing and saving list views. I think my problem pointed more to the DC, however, but I'll keep this in mind.

Comment: Are you using any ajax thing on the site page which is causing problem?

Comment: Some sites do have jquery, but most don't. The problem even occurred while using OOB pages like editing a list view