# SharePoint 2013 - user suddenly logged in with other user's credentials - how is that possible?

Tags: active-directory, security, credentials

We recently had the following problem with SharePoint 2013:

User A suddenly was logged in on his computer with the name of another user (user B).
Both use Windows 7 and Google chrome as browser.

User A claims, that he just opened a Link to the SharePoint portal in his browser and was logged in automatically.

**How is that possible?**

**How could we reproduce this error?**

*Remark:* To my knowledge, user B has never used the computer of user A and therefore should also never have entered his password on this computer.

How can we find out what happened and how we can avoid it?

Did anyone else here have a smiliar problem?

Comment: Is user B's name on any other part of user A's account? E.g. Outlook, Lync/Skype?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, could you please explain? A and B are colleages, they often send e-mails to each other, so each one has the other one in his Outlook Address book.  They belong to the same team and therefore are member of the same AD security group. We do not use Lync. I'm not sure if both have skype installed, but I think it's now part of Office 2013 which is used in the company. There is a MS Exchange Server.

Comment: Was there any any other confirmation that the user was logged onto the wrong account apart from the name? (e.g wrong profile picture, or access?). I am curious if the attributes of user A's account were manually (accidentally) updated.

Was this an isolated incident or has it persisted?

Check the workstation's credential manager (control panel > credential manager) to see if any credentials are saved there.

Comment: thanks, I did not know about this credentials manager. However, at user A's computer, there is nothing listed there (however on mine, there is a sharepoint password mentioned). User A furthermore has stored his (own) login credentials in Chrome's preferences (but we did not found anything from other users).

Comment: Did it happen the one time, or has user B's information continued to show up on user A's workstation?

Did user A see any additional information relating to user b apart from the difference in name?

Comment: @imoses: at least we could not reproduce it yet. Unfortunately, user A logged off quickly so we could not check if it was just the display of the wrong user name or if he really had the wrong "identity".

Comment: @mBBe I am facing similar issue. Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you please share the solution..

Comment: User A knows User B's password. Tell him/her to admit it :) It explains why user A logged off quickly :)

Comment: @RohitWaghela: It did not turn up for a long time, so it seems to be solved, but I do not know what was changed and what was the solution finally. I'm very sorry - I'll try to ask the colleagues in IT.

Comment: @DeepuNair: not funny.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a long shot but I'll post it anyway. I had a similar issue but it happened to everyone who logged on. When I would open SP it would show my name. Then, John Doe would open SP and it would show my name instead of his. When I would refresh my browser it would show John Doe's name. It was the craziest thing. It turns out that our load balancer was missing a config setting necessary for using Kerberos authentication with SP 2013.

Comment: thanks, that sounds interesting. 2 questions: (1) do you have more details about the right (and wrong) configuration? (2) in your case, did the browser only show the wrong name or did people really have the wrong permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this post as well. 
[Incorrect user name displaying on page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94337/incorrect-user-name-displaying-on-page?newreg=5bd88d6426114da6b93ab177b265994e)

1. Distributed Cache in sharepoint may cause this issue.
2. Output Cache in ISS also.